# Creating multiple data tables programmatically and structuring classes

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project where I will end up opening multiple text files.

Each of these text files will then be split into tables of data.

My initial thoughts were that I wanted to keep as much code away from the UI as possible and that I should create a class DataSetClass with a public method OpenFile.

The DataSet would be created as a global inside this class and then all my other functions for sorting the data or getting information from that particular dataset would be inside that class. However, since making the class, I believe I am unable to actually get at that data now and that instead, I should create a new DataSet and then start a class that takes the dataSet and modifies it by adding the tables. But I am worried that this would be feature envy?

In addition to this, I am struggling with how to add multiple DataTables to a DataSet.

In my code below I add the DataTable to a DataSet after I have put all the relevant data into it. However, I end up just adding the exact same DataTable into the DataSet each time and only ever end up with one table.

```
for (int data_table = 1; data_table < header_location.Count; data_table++) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SaveHeaderInfo(dt, header_location[data_table], split_data_list);
    SaveDataUntilStop(dt, start_location[data_table], split_data_list);

    dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
    //dt.Reset();
}
```

When using the dt.Reset line, it simply wipes all the data even after the table has been added to the dataset.

I presume that this is probably because the .add function actually just inserts a pointer to the table into the dataset. So how would I create an entirely new datatable each time?

Thank you

EDIT: Adding Extra Code:

```
private void SaveDataUntilStop(DataTable dt, int start, List<string[]> split_data_list)
    {
        string[] row = new string[400];
        for (int i = start + 1; i < split_data_list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (split_data_list[i][0] != "STOP")
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < split_data_list[i].Length; j++)
                    row[j] = split_data_list[i][j];
                CheckColumnCountAndAdd(dt, row);
            }
            else
                return;
        }
    }

    private void SaveHeaderInfo(DataTable dt, int location, List<string[]> list)
    {
        CheckColumnCountAndAdd(dt, list[location + 1]);
        CheckColumnCountAndAdd(dt, list[location + 2]);
    }

    private void CheckColumnCountAndAdd(DataTable dt, string[] str_to_add)
    {
        while (str_to_add.Length > dt.Columns.Count)
        {
            AddColumn(dt);
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(str_to_add);
    }
```

Comment: You *are* creating a new datatable each time. `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` is executing at the start of each loop. Are you sure you're getting the same table multiple times?

Comment: No, I'm not. I meant to say that the table that I end up with inside the dataset only contains the information from the last table that is scanned.

The results for the first table are lost and do not create their own table within dataSet.

Comment: Maybe you can post your SaveHeaderInfo and SaveDataUntilStop

Comment: Added, but I don't think it makes a difference?

Comment: So, multiple tables with the same data? Or just one table?

Comment: It creates just one table, with the last part of data in it. However, I would like to create a table for each of the sections of data and store them in dataSet.